# Angular custom directive - two way binding which always sets attribute to true or false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm creating a custom Angular directive for a slide in menu which needs to watch a couple of attributes and one of those attributes needs to be two way bound to the main controller scope (sometimes). However, sometimes the attribute will not be added by the developer so it needs to be added automatically and set to the default (false). So, the directive can be used like this.

```
<slide-menu position="right" is-open="menuIsOpen"></slide-menu>
```

or like this:

```
<slide-menu></slide-menu>
```

When used the first way the main controller will be able to open and close the menu by changing the value of the boolean $scope.menuIsOpen.

When used without supplying the is-open attribute it should default to false and is obviously used internally and by a child toggle directive.

An additional complication is that whether the attribute is supplied by the developer or not it should exist in the DOM. so in the second example above the directive would set itself to false by default and add the attribute is-open="false" to the DOM?

The reason for requiring is-open="false/true" in the DOM at all times is that the menu is actually operated using CSS tansitions which use the following selector:

```
slide-menu[is-active="true"]{
    // Slide the menu in using transforms/transitions
}
```

There is a jsfiddle here which shows how far I have got.

http://jsfiddle.net/jonhobbs/gEPvE/

Obviously it doesn't work, but it shows how I have tried to set a default and how I have tried to use @ and & on the isolated scope for a one time binding (the menu position) and a 2 way bound expression for the is-open variable.

I'm clearly a long way from achieving what I need but any advice would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gEPvE/38/
I took the one you started and updated it to act like you specified.

You can make a two way binding value optional by adding a ? on the scope definition.

Like this

```
{
    scope: {
        'isOpen':'=?'
    }
}
```

Now the is-open attribute is optional.
Then you can set the default value in the directive controller, like you had started to do.

Next, in order to synchronize the DOM attribute with the scope value you can use $watch.

```
$scope.$watch('isOpen', function(val) {
    $element.attr('is-open', val);
});
```

Finally, I changed the second 'slideMenuToggle' directive to wrap/transclude its element in order to add an ng-click handler.  This is mainly to avoid any nastiness with calling $scope.$apply yourself.

Let me know if that works for you.

---

**EDIT**

Answering your question in the comment, you can pass a value directly without having it be bound to the scope, you just need to wrap the value in quotes.

For example

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <hello world='imOnScope'></hello>
</div>
```

Assuming 'hello' is a directive with a scope of 'world': '=?' then angular will assign a reference to the parent scope's 'imOnScope' object to the directive's $scope.world member, allowing a two way binding scenario.

To just provide a value directly you may do something like this

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <hello world="'directValue'"></hello>
</div>
```

In this scenario angular will just assign 'directValue' to the directive's $scope.world member.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that almost works exactly how I want it to work. Something I may not be understanding properly though, if I want to use =? does that mean the attribute has to be two way bound to something on the scope? If I wanted the developer to be able to use position="right" to just set the value OR position="position" to bind it to $scope.position, is there a way of doing that? basically I want the developer t be able to just set an attribute, or bind it to the scope, whatever suits them best.

Comment: Check the edit and see if that answers your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ngTouch to your module.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch']);
```

And add this script:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-touch.js

Comment: Thanks, it is in my original project, just not in my jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason for requiring is-open="false/true" in the DOM at all times
>   is that the menu is actually operated using CSS tansitions which use
>   the following selector

Forcing directive attributes to be appropriate for css selectors is terrible idea. As you correctly stated, they are for developers. So add a class to the element dynamically.

It seems that you're misusing `&`, it would be ok to set up a callback, but since you don't do this, in its current state you can end up with one-way `@` with confidence.

I guess it can be something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gEPvE/32/) (just added ngTouch and ng-controller for parent scope).

---

You could replace

```
$scope.watch('isOpen', function () {
    $element.toggleClass('opened', $scope.isOpen);
});
```

with

```
$scope.watch('isOpen', function () {
    $attrs.isOpen = !!$scope.isOpen;
});
```

and get the behaviour you're asking for, easy as that. Ok, it is boolean now, and it reflects the scope, and you can use `[is-open=true]` selector. But guess what will happen with your binding? Broken. Fortunately, you can do

```
$scope.watch('isOpen', function () {
    $element.attr('is-open', !!$scope.isOpen);
});
```

instead. Voila, we tricked Angular because it doesn't look after jqlite. But what will will happen with the binding when the directive will be re-compiled for any reason?  Again, isOpen's binding is non-existing 'true' or 'false' scope variable. Broken.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but there are many reasons why using attribute selectors is much cleaner and neater in my project and it's becoming an increasingly popular technique. I'd still like to find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Also, if I use the @ binding then it will only be one way and something internal in the directive (e.g.the child toggle control) making a change to isOpen wouldn't get propagated to the parent controller scope, right?

Comment: Yes, `@ ` supposes that you don't need to report the isOpen state back. You can use `=` of course (and it will be `is-open="mainMenuOpen"` then, but it will change the parent scope even if you don't need it, to avoid this use `getMainMenuOpen()` instead.

Comment: Popular among who? It is hard to believe that anyone with some level of expertise would recommend such a technique in the context of Angular. Exactly for the reason stated in the answer update. You can add an additional attribute that reflects the state if you want it this way, but it shouldn't be `is-open`.

Comment: Do you not think that <slide-menu position="right" is-open="true class="slideMenu isOpen positionRight"></slideMenu> is a lot of unnecessary duplication when CSS attribute selectors are very fast these days, it's so much cleaner to write <slide-menu position="right" is-open="true></slideMenu> and style that. It's never been a problem for me until I came to write my own Angular Directive. What's more, CSS's attribute~="something" selector allows for some very cool stuff and people have been using them to style form elements for years so I don't see a problem. See this: http://amcss.github.io/

Comment: This is actually a much better explanation: http://glenmaddern.com/articles/introducing-am-css

Comment: Estus, You're just repeating what's already been shown in my answer.  Watching the directive's isOpen value and re-writing the element attribute.  Yes, if for some reason the directive is recompiled after the attribute is re-written it wouldn't work, but when (if ever) does that actually happen.  I can't think of a situation.

Comment: Sure. These guys are bored designers. Not programmers. In Angular any custom attribute means that it is required by some directive. This habit is shared by other modern frontend developments - classes are  for presentation, attrs are for presentation logic. You can use any selectors in css when it's convenient, but this is obviously not the case. If you want to be able to make a binding in attribute, don't use it for anything else. Btw, why would you care about classes are added by the directive itself dynamically?